# How to bypass errors when compiling a C code on macOS

Tags: macos, compilation

I am an IT student and for my studies I need to (to compare C and Java), compile a code on my machine using gcc. The problem is that macOS isn't letting me because it actually prevents an out of bounds from an array, but I know it is possible to compile it on Linux.

So my question is does someone know if it is possible to "bypass" this error and compile.

Here's my code and the error

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int tab[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    printf("%s\n", tab[100]);
}
```

The error

```
segmentation_fault.c:6:17: warning: array index 100 is past the end of the array
      (which contains 10 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
        printf("%s\n", tab[100]);
```

Comment: You're only getting a compiler warning, not an error which stopped the compilation as far as I can tell from the warning message you posted. The compilation should have still been successful. Check to see if an executable `a.out` or `segmentation_fault` was produced.

Comment: Wow yes, I didn't check, my fault. Thank you for replying that quickly !